# memmove in osdev meaty-skeleton: why does it have these if/else statements?

Tags: c, libc, osdev

In the [os-dev meaty skeleton tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/Meaty_Skeleton) this is the implementation of `memmove`:

```
#include <string.h>


void* memmove(void* dstptr, const void* srcptr, size_t size) {
    unsigned char* dst = (unsigned char*) dstptr;
    const unsigned char* src = (const unsigned char*) srcptr;
    if (dst < src) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            dst[i] = src[i];
    } else {
        for (size_t i = size; i != 0; i--)
            dst[i-1] = src[i-1];
    }
    return dstptr;
}
```

They check whether the `dst` pointer is less than `src`, if so they just move the memory.
If not they move the memory in reverse order. But why?

Does that handle some edge case?

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove` ?

Comment: No I do not know the difference. But I'm reading about it now that you've pointed that out.

Comment: So it is handling that difference :)

Comment: Imagine what would happen if the source and destination regions overlap...

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much :D